# HttpUrlConnection working with one url but not with another url

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

One URL works well with HttpUrlConnection in asynctask but another still posting and requesting the same data crashes the app.

but the same server directory has other files and they DoInput and DoOutput successfully

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    try {

        getter_url = new URL("this one returns successfully");
        getter_url0 = new URL("this one just crashes the app");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
    afbah= params[0];
    if (afbah.equals("whfiavbkjnfdl"))
    {
        String kbfisy= params[1];
        try
        {
            try {
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) getter_url0.openConnection();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("gisyfgb", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(kbfisy, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder ANSWER = new StringBuilder();
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                ANSWER.append(line).append("\n");
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
```

I really really can't understand why the two URL's will be acting differently

On postman API it results success the two URL's but the HttpUrlConnection results success for the first url and error for the second one.

please ask me for any information you need to help

Comment: why not using volley for api call: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

What are the example URLs?
It is possible that the URL is not parsed correctly, try this approach:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URI uri = new URI(
    url.getProtocol(),
    url.getUserInfo(),
    url.getHost(),
    url.getPort(),
    url.getPath(),
    url.getQuery(),
    url.getRef()
);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uri.toASCIIString()).openConnection();
```